# Removing black pixel if they are in a cluster of 8 or less

Tags: python, pandas, opencv, numpy

I'm not sure how to tackle this, I have a list of black and white pixels such as;

```
x = [255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
 255 255 255 255 255 255 255   0   0   0 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
 255 255 255 255 255 255 255   0   0   0   0   0   0 255 255 255 255 255
 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
 255 255   0   0 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
 255]
```

I'm looking for a python way of doing something similar to this,

```
if x[2] = 0 
then look ahead 8 places, 
if all x[2] to x[10] are 0 and x[11] = 255 change all to 255
if all are not 0 
see if all x[2] to x[9] are zero 
...
...
...
see if x[2] to x[3] are zero
```

What I habe so far doesn't seem to be working

```
for w in range(len(x)):
        if x[w] == 0 and x[w+8] == 0 and x[w+9] == 255:
            print thresh1[h][w]
        elif x[w] == 0 and x[w+7] == 0 and x[w+8] == 255:
            print thresh1[h][w]
        elif x[w] == 0 and x[w+6] == 0 and x[w+8] == 255:
            print thresh1[h][w]
        elif x[w] == 0 and x[w+5] == 0 and x[w+8] == 255:
            print thresh1[w]
        elif x[w] == 0 and x[w+4] == 0 and x[w+8] == 255:
            print thresh1[w]
        elif x[w] == 0 and x[w+3] == 0 and x[w+8] == 255:
            print thresh1w]
        elif x[w] == 0 and x[w+2] == 0 and x[w+8] == 255:
            print thresh1[h][w]
        elif x[w] == 0 and x[h][w+1] == 0 and x[w+8] == 255:
            print thresh1[h][w]
        elif x[w] == 0 and x[w+1] == 255:
            print x[w]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This might help - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_closing.html

Comment: My first approach had a bug inside. Now my example works. Just run the code in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution seems to be a little complicated and might be improved but it works:

```
import numpy as np
my_list = np.array([255]*100)
my_list[10:17] = 0
my_list[20:30] = 0
print(my_list)
del_list = []
count = 0
current_del_list = []
for iterator, value in enumerate(my_list):
    if value < 255:
        current_del_list += [iterator]
        count+=1
        print(current_del_list)
    else:
        if count > 8:
            count = 0
            current_del_list = []
        else:
            del_list += current_del_list
            current_del_list = []
            count=0
my_list[del_list]=255
my_list = list(my_list)
print(my_list)
```

For every element in your list I'm testing if its below 255. If so, a counter is incremented. And if this counter is below 8 when the next 255 raises, its adding a list of current positions to the `del_list`. Later all values at the positions in the `del_list` are set to 255 in `my_list`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use morphological [opening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closing_(morphology)) operation.

```
In [131]: from scipy.ndimage.morphology import grey_opening

In [132]: grey_closing(np.array(x), structure=np.ones(8))
Out[132]:
array([255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255])
```